# Submitting app to app store error

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

When I submit my app to AppStore, I get this error:

> ERROR ITMS-90149: "This bundle is invalid. The value of the CFBundleDocumentTypes key in the Info.plist must be an array of dictionaries, with each dictionary containing at least the CFBundleTypeName key."

In my Info.plist, I add :

```js
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
        <string>public.jpeg</string>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
        <string>Owner</string>
        <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>public.jpeg</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Error persists.

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your doesn't respect the format for the diferents keys.

```
<dict>
   <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
   <string>My File Format</string>
   <key>CFBundleTypeIconFiles</key>
       <array>
           <string>MySmallIcon.png</string>
           <string>MyLargeIcon.png</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
       <array>
           <string>com.example.myformat</string>
       </array>
   <key>LSHandlerRank</key>
   <string>Owner</string>
</dict>
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html

Comment: This answer is useful. In my project the array of dictionaries was perfect. But error was due to extra EMPTY dictionary entry "<dict/>" at the end. Once removed it worked. So it is required to properly check the array of dictionaries with valid dictionary.